# Ubuntu 16.04 server loses default route on restart

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gateway, ip-routing

One of my Ubuntu servers always loses its default route when restarted.  I have a second server which has an almost identical set up which works fine.  I am not sure when the problem started but it first became an issue when we started auto patching so the servers get rebooted every month.

```
rful011@secesprd02:~$ ifconfig
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:e9:d4:a0:6f:50  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27405882 errors:0 dropped:127 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11898380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:38129519206 (38.1 GB)  TX bytes:14527843371 (14.5 GB)

bond0.1060 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:e9:d4:a0:6f:50  
          inet addr:10.6.0.68  Bcast:10.6.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4349473 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2832180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:36350288670 (36.3 GB)  TX bytes:13842264977 (13.8 GB)
```

and in `/etc/networks/interfaces`:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    post-up ifenslave bond0 enp2s0f0 enp2s0f1
    pre-down ifenslave -d bond0 enp2s0f0 enp2s0f1
    bond-slaves none
    bond-mode 4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp_rate 0

auto enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet manual

auto enp2s0f1
iface enp2s0f1 inet manual

auto bond0.1060
iface bond0.1060 inet static
    address 10.6.0.68
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.6.0.0
    broadcast 10.6.0.255
    gateway 10.6.0.254
```

These files are *identical*  (except for the IP address) to the setup on the machine that works.

This is an important production server so I really don't want to go bouncing it often to test stuff !
Does anyone have any ideas on how to diagnose what is going on.

Comment: Maybe while changing your update regimen you installed all available updates on one machine, but only security-pocket updates on the other? Compare `dpkg -l`!

Comment: The updates are automated and not managed by me.  There are numerous minor difference in package version which is odd and something I will take up with the the infrastructure folk.  I think that only the security updates are being applied.